# Iptables rules for blocking a particular website

Tags: linux, iptables

I have created a rule to block a particular website (facebook.com in this case) which is given below:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d www.facebook.com -j LOG --log-prefix "Accessing Facebook:"
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d www.facebook.com -j DROP
```

Now the website is blocked after this. But I am trying to understand the logs:

```
[root@localhost centos]# cat /var/log/messages | grep Facebook
Nov  4 16:00:22 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.71.36 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=16774 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59020 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  4 16:00:22 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.71.36 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=16774 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59020 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  4 16:00:22 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.71.36 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=52984 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59021 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  4 16:00:22 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.71.36 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=52984 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59021 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  4 16:00:38 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.81.36 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=51020 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=55776 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  4 16:00:38 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.81.36 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=51020 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=55776 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  4 16:00:38 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.71.36 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=16775 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59020 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  4 16:00:38 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.71.36 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=16775 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59020 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  4 16:00:38 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.81.36 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=51021 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=55776 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
Nov  4 16:00:38 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.81.36 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=51021 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=55776 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
Nov  4 16:00:38 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.81.36 LEN=557 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=51022 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=55776 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
Nov  4 16:00:38 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.81.36 LEN=557 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=51022 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=55776 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
Nov  4 16:00:38 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.81.36 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=51023 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=55776 DPT=443 WINDOW=15544 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
Nov  4 16:00:38 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.81.36 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=51023 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=55776 DPT=443 WINDOW=15544 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0
Nov  4 16:00:38 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.81.36 LEN=91 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=51024 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=55776 DPT=443 WINDOW=15544 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
Nov  4 17:42:25 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.71.36 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=52568 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59091 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  4 17:42:25 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.71.36 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=52568 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59091 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  4 17:42:41 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.71.36 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=43251 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59090 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  4 17:42:41 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.71.36 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=43251 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59090 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  4 17:42:41 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.71.36 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=52569 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59090 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  4 17:42:41 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.71.36 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=52569 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59091 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  4 17:43:13 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.71.36 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=53725 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59091 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  4 17:43:13 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.71.36 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=53725 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59092 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  4 17:43:14 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.71.36 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=53726 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59092 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  4 17:43:14 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.71.36 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=53726 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59092 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  4 17:43:16 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.71.36 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=53727 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59092 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  4 17:43:16 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.71.36 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=53727 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59092 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  4 17:43:20 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.71.36 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=53728 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59092 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  4 17:43:20 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.71.36 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=53728 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59092 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  4 17:43:28 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.71.36 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=53729 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59092 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
Nov  4 17:43:28 localhost kernel: Accessing Facebook:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=10.0.2.15 DST=31.13.71.36 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=53729 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=59092 DPT=443 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

Is there a way to make out that the website is blocked by looking at the logs? If so what exactly should I look for? (Or since the message I added "Accessing Facebook" is coming in the log it's obvious that the website is blocked)

In the 9th through 15th lines of output, why am I receiving the ACK packets?

Comment: This answer on serverfault may be of interest: http://serverfault.com/a/486096

Comment: 1) facebook IP might change, you are only blocking a single IP among all facebook IPs. 2) external site access is usualy blocked by a proxy blacklist/whitelist/user level setting.